# Swift Temp CoreData object can not set ivars when context is nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a CoreData object I would like to instantiate (to use temporarily) but I do not want to save or insert into the context for persistence.

My Class definition for the object I would like to create is thus:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(USubmission)

class USubmission: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var subid: NSNumber
```

I create the object like this (to use temporarily but not to persist)

```
let entitiyDesc = NSEntityDescription()
entitiyDesc.name = "USubmission"
entitiyDesc.managedObjectClassName = "USubmission"
let sub = USubmission.init(entity: entitiyDesc, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: nil)
```

However when I set one of the temporary object's ivars I get the following error:

```
sub.subid = 0
```

Error:

> [USubmission setSubid:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I inspected the object and it looks like the correct object  and not a NSManagedObject object.

Why do I get this error when the context is nil (temp object) versus when there is a context?

Comment: As @messeb points out in his answer below, the problem stems from the entity description.  You have created  it from scratch, and it is distinct from the definition provided in your model (albeit it has the same name and model class).  Specifying a context in the `entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` class method provides a link to the model (context -> psc -> model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an entity description from the your ManagedObjectContext:

```
let entitiyDesc = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("USubmission", inManagedObjectContext: **yourContext**)
```

If you don't want to save the object, thats created with the entity, than pass **nil** to *insertIntoManagedObjectContext*, like you already do:

```
let sub = USubmission.init(entity: entitiyDesc, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: nil)
```

Comment: That was it!  Just needed to pass in a valid context for the NSEntityDescription and it's working now.  Thanks for your help!!